# After imorting posts from another blog double line breaks have been replaced with single line breaks

Tags: import

i wonder if anyone else has had this problem and knows how to fix it.

After importing all posts from my old wordpress installation, using the default xml import tool, all double line breaks have been replaced with single line breaks

this has severely disrupted the formatting of the text in my posts, as normally wordpress interprets a double line break as a paragraph, but after importing, the text looks very squashed together as the single line breaks are interpreted as `<br>`

does anyone know of a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php before exporting
It will run the content through same wpautop() function that's used to display posts.

```
function codelight_content_export($content) {
 return wpautop($content);
}
add_filter('the_content_export', 'codelight_content_export', 999);
```

Comment: thanks! i will try it if i have that problem again in future